# What does time specified in a stack trace mean?

Tags: go, stack-trace

I'm reading stack trace of a go program for debugging.

```
goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
go.elastic.co/apm.(*Tracer).loop.func2(0xc000042420, 0xc0000423c0, 0x1551980, 0xc0004da100, 0xc000074300, 0xc000001080, 0xc00000e018)
    /app/vendor/go.elastic.co/apm/tracer.go:803 +0x21a
created by go.elastic.co/apm.(*Tracer).loop
    /app/vendor/go.elastic.co/apm/tracer.go:800 +0x36e

goroutine 8 [chan receive, 21 minutes]:
github.com/getsentry/sentry-go.(*HTTPTransport).worker(0xc0003025b0)
    /app/vendor/github.com/getsentry/sentry-go/transport.go:387 +0x77
created by github.com/getsentry/sentry-go.(*HTTPTransport).Configure.func1
    /app/vendor/github.com/getsentry/sentry-go/transport.go:255 +0x3e
```

What does the time `21 minutes` signify in the second go routine? This time is absent from the first one. I looked up in the documentation but couldn't find what this time is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the approximate amount of time the goroutine was blocked. It is only displayed if the amount of time the goroutine was blocked is at least 1 minute.

You can look at the code that produces this output in the go runtime source, [`runtime/traceback.go`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/runtime/traceback.go;l=898) (linked is the go1.16.6 version of the code).

Comment: Thank you. But why doesn't it list the time for first one?

Comment: @Lokesh Because if it's less than a minute, it's not printed: `if waitfor >= 1 {print...}`

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thank you